# C# LINQ with wrong order?

Tags: c#, linq

I have one list of objects that I want to order, but I can't figure it out how to do it with LINQ, maybe I'm thinking that LINQ works in a different way.

I can simple workaround the problem by using the where clause in the sample, but I would like to understand what's going on.

Can anyone explain me why I can't get the expected result in the "values" variable?

Thanks

### Expected result

[order of objects in the list "values"]:

```
new MyClass{Ordinal = 1, A = true, B = Status.Released, C = 3}
new MyClass{Ordinal = 0, A = true, B = Status.Released, C = 2}
new MyClass{Ordinal = 4, A = true, B = Status.Skipped, C = 5}
new MyClass{Ordinal = 2, A = true, B = Status.Skipped, C = 4}
new MyClass{Ordinal = 3, A = false, B = Status.Skipped, C = 1}
```

## Sample

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var lst = new List<MyClass>{ 
            new MyClass{Ordinal = 0, A = true, B = Status.Released, C = 2},
            new MyClass{Ordinal = 1, A = true, B = Status.Released, C = 3},
            new MyClass{Ordinal = 2, A = true, B = Status.Skipped, C = 4},
            new MyClass{Ordinal = 3, A = false, B = Status.Skipped, C = 1},
            new MyClass{Ordinal = 4, A = true, B = Status.Skipped, C = 5}
        };


        var workaround = lst.Where(i => i.B != Status.Skipped && i.B != Status.Cancelled)
            .OrderByDescending(i => i.A)
            .ThenByDescending(i => i.C)
            .ToList();

        var values = lst.OrderByDescending(i => i.A)
            .ThenBy(i => i.B == Status.Skipped && i.B == Status.Cancelled)
            .ThenByDescending(i => i.C)
            .ToList();

        /* order of the objects in "values"
            new MyClass{Ordinal = 4, A = true, B = Status.Skipped, C = 5}
            new MyClass{Ordinal = 2, A = true, B = Status.Skipped, C = 4}
            new MyClass{Ordinal = 1, A = true, B = Status.Released, C = 3}
            new MyClass{Ordinal = 0, A = true, B = Status.Released, C = 2}
            new MyClass{Ordinal = 3, A = false, B = Status.Skipped, C = 1}
        */
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    public int Ordinal { get; set; }

    public bool A { get; set; }
    public Status B { get; set; }
    public int C { get; set; }
}

public enum Status
{
    Unknown,
    Released,
    Cancelled,
    Received,
    Processing,
    Succeeded,
    Failed,
    Skipped
}
```

Comment: Bools are ordered in the order, `false` then `true` - is that your issue?

Comment: Your `ThenBy()` does nothing - status can't be Skipped and Cancelled at the same time, so there's no ordering there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The lambda expression

```
i => i.B == Status.Skipped && i.B == Status.Cancelled
```

which is used for the `ThenBy` function maps every instance of `MyClass` to `false`, supposing that that `Status.Skipped` and `Status.Cancelled` are different values; this results in no useful ordering. Perhaps you mean

```
i => i.B != Status.Skipped && i.B != Status.Cancelled
```

to order the entries with statuses `Status.Skipped` and `Status.Cancelled` to the bottom.

Comment: I think he wants them at the bottom, not top, so should probably be `i.B != Status.Skipped && i.B != Status.Cancelled`

Comment: @James Thanks for the comment, one could also negate the condition. I will update my answer,

Comment: Yes, that would be simpler :)

Comment: Thanks Codor, actually your 1st anwser is exactly what I want!
And thanks for the explanation, obvious that what I did doesn't make sense.
i => i.B == Status.Skipped && i.B == Status.Cancelled